# Implementing DFS with prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to write DFS (Depth First Search) code with Prolog

```
search(Istate,Goal):-
    findPath([(Istate,null)], [], Goal).

findPath([], _, _):- %empty open list
   !, write("No solution found"),nl.
findPath([(Goal,Parent)|_], Closed, Goal):- %Goal has been reached
   printSolution((Goal,Parent), Closed).
findPath([State|RestOfOpen], Closed, Goal):-
    getChildren(State, RestOfOpen, Closed, Children),
    concatenate(Children, RestOfOpen, NewOpen),
    findPath(NewOpen, [State|Closed], Goal).

getChildren((State, _), Open, Closed, Children):-
    bagof((X,State), move(State,X), Open, Closed, Children).

concatenate([],L,L):- !.
concatenate(L,[],L):- !.
concatenate([H|T], L, [H|R]):-
    concatenate(T, L, R).

printSolution((Istate,null),_):-
    !, write(Istate), nl.
printSolution((State, Parent), Closed):-
    SearchInClosed(Parent, Closed, (Parent, GrandParent), NewClosed),
    printSolution((Parent, GrandParent), NewClosed),
    write(State), nl.

SearchInClosed(State, [(State, Parent)|RestOfClosed], (State, Parent), RestOfClosed):- !.
SearchInClosed(State, [H|RestOfClosed], R, [H|NewClosed]):-
    SearchInClosed(State, RestOfClosed, R, NewClosed).

move(State,NewState):- .%to be implemented
```

But I am getting the following error "Syntax error: Operator expected"
I really do not know how to solve the problem

Comment: What line number does you error message point to? Start there. By the way, if what you're showing is what you are trying to execute, then `move(State,NewState):- .%to be implemented` is a syntax error. You can't define a predicate clause with `:-` and an empty body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if your code is correct, but the syntax errors are with `SearchInClosed` and with your last rule. `SearchInClosed` should start with a lower case letter, like `searchInClosed`. Everything that starts with an upper case letter is a variable.

The next issue is with your last rule. You can take out the `:-` to get it to compile; `:-` requires some code to follow it. It is like an implication, and for an implication to make sense you need to have something at the other end.

Below is a version which will compile. It still contains some warnings, but I suspect they are a result of the code being incomplete. To reiterate, I did not check anything for correctness.

```
search(Istate,Goal):-
    findPath([(Istate,null)], [], Goal).

findPath([], _, _):- %empty open list
   !, write("No solution found"),nl.
findPath([(Goal,Parent)|_], Closed, Goal):- %Goal has been reached
   printSolution((Goal,Parent), Closed).
findPath([State|RestOfOpen], Closed, Goal):-
    getChildren(State, RestOfOpen, Closed, Children),
    concatenate(Children, RestOfOpen, NewOpen),
    findPath(NewOpen, [State|Closed], Goal).

getChildren((State, _), Open, Closed, Children):-
    bagof((X,State), move(State,X), Open, Closed, Children).

concatenate([],L,L):- !.
concatenate(L,[],L):- !.
concatenate([H|T], L, [H|R]):-
    concatenate(T, L, R).

printSolution((Istate,null),_):-
    !, write(Istate), nl.
printSolution((State, Parent), Closed):-
    searchInClosed(Parent, Closed, (Parent, GrandParent), NewClosed),
    printSolution((Parent, GrandParent), NewClosed),
    write(State), nl.

searchInClosed(State, [(State, Parent)|RestOfClosed], (State, Parent), RestOfClosed):- !.
searchInClosed(State, [H|RestOfClosed], R, [H|NewClosed]):-
    searchInClosed(State, RestOfClosed, R, NewClosed).

move(State,NewState).%to be implemented
```

Comment: Thank you.. this really helped.